# Measuring Web application session resource consumption

Tags: java, web-applications, profiling, session-management, memory-profiling

I have this web application that i have created using Wicket, Guice and JPA. I would like to advise my clients on the resource consumption of the application so that i can also advice him on the optimum hardware to purchase. What is the best way of measuring the Memory and CPU consumption per session as well as the network bandwidth requirements? Area there tools for undertaking such measurements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jConsole](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) is now part of the standard JDK and can be used to monitor a JVM. Of course, you will need to create some reasonable load on your application before you measure anything significant. To crete load, have a look at projects like [OpenSTA](http://opensta.org/), [Apache jMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), ...